# Is it possible to stop the time from the moment a user performs an Action until he performs another Action?

Tags: time

I want to do something like a typing game. Would it be possible to create an Action where the user is represented a string. As soon as he presses this action a timer will start until he submits his own written string with another action which would stop the timer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can record starting and end time point by two independent transactions, but how will you check whether it's really typed by human instead of copy-and-paste? If you mean doing this by two actions in one transaction, time limit per each transaction is very short (a few milliseconds), because you should not possess blockchain network exclusively.